# Finding the last specific character type in a string

Tags: regex

I am searching in a string constructed somewhat like this:

```
bla bla bla *Priorities: bla bla - yada yada - Keyword, yada *Terms
```

and I can capture the Keywords like so:

```
\*Priorities:.*?-.*?- (.*?),.*?\*Terms
```

However in some cases there are more or less hyphens:

```
bla bla bla *Priorities: bla bla - yada yada - bla bla - Keyword, yada *Terms
```

I can get that too with:

```
\*Priorities:(.*?-){1,4} (.*?),.*?\*Terms
```

but I am trying to avoid a second capturing group (so I don't have to modify my code).  Is there anyway to do this in some way that searches from the end of the pattern match to the last `.?*-`? and still use the beginning of the string (`*Priorities:`) in the pattern match and thus avoid a second capture group?

Comment: Will [`\*Priorities:.*- ([^,]*),.*?\*Terms`](https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/1) work for you?

Comment: @anubhava It seems to, yes, I even tried making the capture group into - `Keyword1 Keyword2,` Do you mind explaining as I've done a fair amount of regex recently by necessity but am at a loss to understand the logic? You might even put as an answer with details I am happy accept it officially then thanks.

Comment: ok I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to match both input strings:

```
\*Priorities:.*- ([^,]*),.*?\*Terms
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\*Priorities:  # Match literal *Priorities:
.*             # Match 0 or more any character (greedy match)
-              # Match hyphen and space
([^,]*),       # Match 0 or more of non-comma characters followed by a comma
.*?            # Match 0 or more any character (lazy match)
\*Terms        # Match literal *Terms
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/1)

Note that due to lazy match `.*` before hyphen+space we're making sure that we match longest match before last occurrence of hyphen+space.

Answer (score 1):

Match from 1 to 4 groups of non-commas followed by comma. Then a space followed by a keyword, followed by the end sequence.

```
\*Priorities:(?:[^-]+-){1,4} (\w+).*\*Terms
```

Comment: I am sorry I probably confused this because of the pattern I chose. The comma is really superflous here; the key is that I am trying to find test after the last 1 to 4 different hypen/text patterns which has a standard initial and final patterns. So Start: - bla - X End or Start - bla - yada - X End or Start - bla - yada - yada - X End all find X.

Comment: Thanks but that puts me right back to my original issue, having 1-x capture groups. I ended up just changing the code that parses this so that I could indicate which group # has my value in it in the end it was an easier solution.

Comment: The regexp needs to have something that indicates where the keyword is, as distinguished from other words in the string.