# String after last hypen with 1-N Hypens in Regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Given a pattern (https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/2) which can have N # of hypens where I want the text after the last one, how would I request that as I always get the first:

`<details>Fiction - Mystery - Duvall</details>`

`<details>Fiction - Mystery - Horror -  Duvall</details>`

Where I want Duvall in each case.

Disclaimer: for anyone following my questions, I realize this looks a lot like

[Finding the last specific character type in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150414/finding-the-last-specific-character-type-in-a-string)

but I tried to apply that solution to no avail. Possibly not totally understanding it as a relative Regex newbie, just didn't want the person who did answer that to think I ignored them and was asking for duplicate work.

Comment: You don't need to be too specific, use something like `<details>.*?-\s*([^-]*?)</details>` https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
<details>(?:\w+ - *)*(\w+)<\/details>
```

The idea is to match as much as possible inside the (?: ) group, which doesn't cause a backreference to be made, then match the thing you actually care about - the last token. The example below should give a bit more insight into what the syntax means.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/2)

Comment: If I am not mistaken in each case that example is getting everything after the first `-` which mine does too. In each case it should be returning `Duvall`

Comment: OIC, the example you provided did not work, not sure if you meant to update but I pasted your pattern `<details>(?:\w+ - *)*(\w+)<\/details>` in and then updated the sample regex https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/4 and it works perfectly.

Comment: One thing I noticed is it works on a last word but not last words e.g. 'Duvall McNiel' i.e. the string after the last hypen vs the word see here: https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/5

Comment: For what it is worth my actual example has `- Words1-N (String)<` so I made it work like so https://regex101.com/r/iN9hG6/6

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the provided sample input data, this is an XML and should be parsed with *specialized* tools like [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/). To get to the data after the first hyphen, we'll use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) providing the `maxsplit` value of 1 and getting the last item of the result:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<root>
    <details>Fiction - Mystery - Duvall</details>
    <details>Fiction - Mystery - Horror -  Duvall</details>
</root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for details in root.findall("details"):
    text = details.text
    print(text.split(" - ", 1)[1])
```

Prints:

```
Mystery - Duvall
Mystery - Horror -  Duvall
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the split() function is easier to use than RegEx.

```
test_string = "<details>Fiction - Mystery - Horror -  Duvall</details>"
author = test_string.split("-")[-1][2:-10]
```